# Create a symbolic link on Android even though the destination does not exist

Tags: android, bash, shell

I guess the title pretty much explains everything that I'm asking for. Well, I'd like to write a shell Script for my Android device that creates a Symbolic Link to a folder which does not exist. However, I want this Symbolic Link to be created, no matter if the destination folder exists or not. ln -s can't do that on Android. If I try to do that I get this error:
ln: cannot create symbolic link from '/storage/emulated/0/link' to '/system/app/Maps/lib/x86': No such file or directory
/system/app/Maps/lib/x86 really does not exist but can't I create a symbolic link to that folder though? If there's another command than ln on Android I'd like to use this other one if it works.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you create a link to a file that does exist? The real problem seems to be that the file system at /storage/emulated just does not support symlinks.

Comment: Most probably that is the issue. I will use /data/media/0 which is actually the same location but it supports symlinks